# Advice on best way to upload a document to a form without saving it to database?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, thymeleaf

My Java/Springboot/Thymeleaf app has a form called direct bind. On this form there is a modal that pops up when you click a button, in this modal you can attach a file. I am having issues with the submit modal button as I am not sure what to do in my controller... need to append the document to the form & close the modal so that I can continue filling out the form and eventually email the attachment and the forms' input values. 
Do I have to create a variable in my model to temporarily hold the attachment until the directBind form is submitted/emailed out?

Here is the modal html:

```html
<div id="modal" class="modal" data-izimodal-title="Upload a Document">
     <div id="newRequiredDocForm">
         <form enctype="multipart/form-data" th:action="@{/attachDoc}"  method="post" th:object="${newFiles}">
            <div class="row">
                 <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-3 text-right"><label class="modalLabel">Type:</label></div>
                 <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-3 text-right">
                 <label class="modalLabel">File:</label>
               </div>
               <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-7">
                  <input type="file" name="newFiles" id="newFiles" multiple="multiple" style="margin-right:-20px;"/>
               </div>
            </div>
            <br/><br/>
            <div style="text-align: right;"><input type="submit" id="attachNewDoc" value="Submit" class="btn btn-docModal"/></div>
          </form>
      </div>
</div>
```

Controller:

```html
@RequestMapping(value="/attachDoc")
public String attachDoc (Model model,Document document, DirectBind directBind, @RequestParam("newFiles") MultipartFile newFiles) {
        document.setStorage(storageService.store(newFiles));
        model.addAttribute("newFiles", newFiles);
        return "redirect:/directBind";
}
```

Comment: Since the files are uploaded to the server and needs to be stored there (temporarily), how long do you want the files to be retained if the user never submits the main form?

Comment: @Andreas I have to store the docs in the server to get them to append to the form and be attached with the emailed form? If the person does not submit the main form, I don't want the files to be in storage. Also, after the email is sent, I no longer need the attachments stored either.